# Encoding qr code from a set of strings retrieved from databases and files using delimiter with zxing in android

Tags: java, android

I have already tried normal **qr code generator** using **zxing** in android. Now I want to encode a qr code consisting of a set of strings which needs to be retrieved from databases and files. Each string will be separated by a delimiter.

I need help in writing the code for accessing the strings and then finally combining them using delimiter and generating the qr code with zxing in android studio.

Here is my code
XML..

```
<TextView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="QR Code Generator" />

<EditText

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:hint="Enter text to generate"
    android:id="@+id/text"/>

<Button

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_centreHorizontal="true"
    android:text="GENERATE"
    android:id="@+id/gen_btn/>

<View

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:id="@+id/view"/>

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view">

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java..

```
public class GeneratingActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    EditText text;
    Button gen_btn;
    ImageView image;
    String text2Qr;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_generating);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
        gen_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gen_btn);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        gen_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener ()
        {
            public void OnClick(View view)
            {
                text2Qr = text.getText().toString().trim();
                MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
                try
                {
                    BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode("text2Qr", BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200);
                    BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                    Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                catch(WriterException e)
                {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your work please

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya code included